# Water and electricity?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, current

I just put my Ipad Air 3 in my bag, it was raining and forgot to close it such that  when I got home, my Ipad and the inside of my bag was extremely wet. I know a bit of physics but not figure whether or not something could happen to the inner workings of my Ipad (so I am reaching out to the wizards):

Does water affect electricity in any way (e.g. slower flow of electrons, less stable) if the water has not destroyed the whole circuit? More specifically for my case, in case some water slipped inside towards the inner workings, and the Ipad seems to be workings just as great as before, could any of the electronic circuits have been affected?

Comment: If it is working, then it is working unless you see that something isn't. Just let it dry well

Comment: Yes but even something that is working could be working quite differently

Comment: It can create shorts by dissolving stuff in it

Comment: @DKNguyen but then it wouldn't even work, right? So if I can turn it on, there is no risk of shorts`? Assuming that "shorts" means short circuit

Comment: Shorts can be of varying degrees in the same way a cut doesn't necessarily mean dismemberment.

Comment: This is not a task for guesses from first principles, instead look for information from someone who *actually* works on water damaged ipads (for example see Louis Rossman's videos or similar)

Comment: Throw it in a bag of rice, seal, leave sit for several days.

Comment: The good news is that consumer electronics can be surprisingly resilient just because *it's hard for the water to get into the case*. The bad news is it's hard to know whether it's damaged or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately water can be bad for electronics in several ways:

It can create shorts between signal wires, causing logical errors or destroying chips that suddenly have unexpected voltage levels.

It can short out power lines, causing heat that can burn up parts of the device or disable the battery.

It can corrode metals, possibly causing the above two problems now or later, or changing the electrical characteristics such as resistance or capacitance with hard-to-predict results.

Water drops on the loose inside the device could also move around as the device is handled.

To be *certain* the device won't develop problems later on, it should be opened up, inspected and left to dry out. Then again, it might be fine as is. It's just really hard to tell from the outside.

Comment: Much appreciated!! Last one: If it was like 30 water drops on this area: https://ibb.co/yXZ1x1Q - how likely do you *think* that any of the above could happen?

Comment: Sorry I'm not that familiar with iPad, only the general principles. Like Chris Stratton mentioned, the videos of Louis Rossman or other Google search results could give a clue of the risks.